# PHP prepared statements clarification

Tags: php

Can you mix user input data with fixed data in a prepared statement security wise or does each query condition have to have a placeholder?

For example:

```
$code = htmlspecialchars($_GET['code']); // USER INPUT DATA
$status = 'A'; // FIXED

$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT s_id FROM events WHERE s_code = ? AND s_status = ?") or die(mysqli_error());
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $code, $status);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($reference);
```

Or is this also acceptable?

```
$code = htmlspecialchars($_GET['code']); // USER INPUT DATA

$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT s_id FROM events WHERE s_code = ? AND s_status = 'A'") or die(mysqli_error());
$stmt->bind_param('s', $code);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($reference);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are acceptable. Obviously there's no security impact in binding a fixed value from your code, but it may have some performance benefits if various parts of your application (or even different applications) use different hard-coded values for that query.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answer provided by Mureinik, you should also focus on the user input a bit. Prepared statements are effective at preventing SQL injection attacks, but they are not a universal antidote against all types of attacks.

Judging by your example I would say you expect the `$_GET['code']` to be an integer. As an extra layer of security you can (and should) sanitize and also validate the user input. Something along these lines:

```php
// avoid accessing directly super-globals like $_GET, $_POST
// @see Sanitize filters: http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php
$code = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'code', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// @see Validate filters: http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php
$options = array(
    'options' => array(
        'min_range' => 1,
        'max_range' => 1000000,
));

if (!filter_var($code, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)) {
    echo 'Invalid code!';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Max - this is very useful! 
Just a question though - The code is a string though with characters & numbers so would you use this instead?

$code = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'code', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

Comment: yes, in this case you would use the filter: `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`. And if there are some rules for the code then you can use those for validation. Example: if the length is always 5 characters then check the length, if it's composed of 2 digits and 3 characters then use some regex.